# Hibernate JPA QueryBuilder.like

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I recently trying to refactor my Hibernate Session API to JPA API and I ran in to some problems

Here is my old Session code

```
Criteria criteria = session().createCriteria(Book.class);       

    // SEARCH both name, ispn field in the db
    if( search != null && !search.isEmpty() ){
        Criterion name = Restrictions.ilike("name", search, MatchMode.ANYWHERE);  // This use to return a list of similar results..
        Criterion ispn = Restrictions.ilike("ispn", search, MatchMode.ANYWHERE);

        LogicalExpression orExp = Restrictions.or(name, ispn);

        criteria.add(orExp);
    }
```

Here is my try of implementing CriteriaBuilder

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<Book> criteria = builder.createQuery(Book.class);

    Root<Book> root = criteria.from(Book.class);

    criteria.select(root);



    if( search != null && !search.isEmpty() ){

        System.out.println(search);

        Predicate predicateName = builder.like(root.get(Book_.name), search); // root.get(Book_.name) must match exactly `search` for it to return anything.

        // Predicate predicateIspn = builder.like(root.get(Book_.ispn), search);

        criteria.where(predicateName);
    }

    List<Book> books = entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();

    return books;
```

**Questions**

1. `Predicate predicateName = builder.like(root.get(Book_.name), search);`  CirteriaBuilder.like doesn't seem to work I have to make sure `search` matches perfectly to `root.get(Book_.name)` for it to return results.

I have looked at hibernate docs it seems like CriteriaBuilder.like only takes 2 argument one is taken from db mapping`root.get(Book_.name)` compare to input `search` there is no option where I can tell it to MatchMode.ANYWHERE.  Any suggestions? or maybe I use the wrong method?

2. `LogicalExpression orExp = Restrictions.or(name, ispn);` it use to check if the input matches `name` or `ispn`.  But with JPA CriteriaBuilder how would I do this?  I looked around for some tutorials Just couldn't find a tutorial that has a complete CRUD examples...

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. wrap search into '%'+'%' -> builder.like(root.get(Book_.ispn), '%'+search+'%') .

better create util method and reuse it. like :

```
    public staic String wrapToLike(String value) {

        return value == null ? "%" : "%"+value"%";
    }
```

or :

```
//root.get(Book_.name) - path
public Predicate createLikePredicate(CriteriaBuilder builder , Path path , String search)
    return builder.like(path, wrapToLike(search))
}
```

2.

```
 Predicate predicateName = builder.like(root.get(Book_.name), wrapToLike(search)); 
 Predicate predicateIspn = builder.like(root.get(Book_.ispn), wrapToLike(search)); 

 Restrictions.or(predicateName ,predicateIspn);
```

it should looks like :

```
public List<Book> findBooksBySearchKey(String search) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Book> criteria = builder.createQuery(Book.class);
    Root<Book> root = criteria.from(Book.class);
    criteria.select(root);
    applySearchPredicate(builder, criteria, root, search);
    return entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
}

private void applySearchPredicate(CriteriaBuilder builder, CriteriaQuery<Book> criteria, Root<Book> root, String search) {
    if (search != null && search.trim().length() > 0) {
        Predicate predicateName = builder.like(root.get(Book_.name), wrapToLike(search));
        Predicate predicateIspn = builder.like(root.get(Book_.ispn), wrapToLike(search));
        criteria.where(builder.or(predicateName , predicateIspn));
    }
}

public static String wrapToLike(String value) {
    return value == null ? "%" : "%"+value+"%";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the extra suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to SQL LIKE [**CriteriaBuilder.like**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#like(javax.persistence.criteria.Expression,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression)) expects a `pattern` wrapped between two `%`, so you just need to wrap your second `search` element like this : `"%"+search+"%"`:

```
Predicate predicateName = builder.like(root.get(Book_.name), "%"+search+"%");
```

For further details you can check:

- [**CriteriaBuilder.like** documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#like(javax.persistence.criteria.Expression,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression)).
- [**CriteriaBuilder and Dynamic Queries in JPA 2.0**](http://city81.blogspot.com/2011/01/criteriabuilder-and-dynamic-queries-in.html)

Comment: Thanks for the extra links very useful

Answer (score 0):

[MatchMode](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/MatchMode.html#END) is a best util which helps to eliminate direct use of '%' in your hibernate code. But not aware of any such utility in JPA.

Using best practices, for wrapping search into '%'+'%, we can reuse the code of MatchMode enum itself to have a solution:

```
public staic String wrapToLike(String value) {
    return value == null ? "%" : MatchMode.ANYWHERE.toMatchString(value);
}
```

> MatchMode.ANYWHERE.toMatchString(str) : toMatchString method converts
>   the value string to enum from which it is called.

Options:

- ANYWHERE: '%' + value + '%'
- END: '%' + value
- START: value + '%'
- EXACT: value